# Python: Error en text de Label

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Mi objetivo es en una ventana, colocar un Label, el cual al inicio no contiene algun caracter, pero a lo largo de interactuar a lo largo de la ventana con diferentes widges, el Label va tomando diferentes Textos, mi Label es el siguiente:

```
self.messages = Label(text = "", fg = "red").grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2,sticky = W + E)
```

Y a lo largo del programa se encuentran varios:

```
self.messages["text"] = "Texto"
```

Que contienen diferentes textos, el error que me sale en pantalla es el siguiente:

```
File "Aplicacion.wpy.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.messages["text"] = "Texto" 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

***Repl Closed***
```

¿Estoy cometiendo algún error de sintaxis?, ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás usando tkinter. No soy experto, pero encontré dos posibles problemas.

Lo primero es que si vas a referenciar self.messages después de:

```
self.messages = Label(text = "", fg = "red").grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2,sticky = W + E)
```

pienso que debes separarlo en dos líneas, pues creo que al aplicar el método grid al Label no te devuelve nada, y se le asigna "None"  a la variable. Imagina que grid sea una función que actúa sobre el Label creado, pero no devuelve nada, y por tanto no se podría asignar así.

Yo pondría:

```
self.messages = Label(text = "", fg = "red")
self.messages.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2,sticky = W + E)
```

Con respecto a cambiar el texto después de crear la etiqueta, si no te funciona directamente puedes usar la clase StringVar del propio tkinter. Algo similar a:

```
texto = StringVar()
texto.set("")
self.messages = Label(textvariable=texto,...)
```

y después actualizar el valor del texto con los métodos de la propia clase. Seguro que si buscas en Google te salen ejemplos sencillos.